# md5sum relationship between splite files and combined large file

Tags: linux, split, md5sum

I have two file.00 and file.01, split from file. And I have md5sum of file.00 and file.01, and also original file. Can I check if file.00 + file.01 equal to file based on the md5sum values?

Comment: You can't do that based only on md5 sums. The only way is to concatenate your files and compare the md5 sum from the result against the original file, which is far less efficient, obviously.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Thanks! Seems duplicated.